# Pandas: normalize values by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-wrangling

I find it hard to explain with words what I want to achieve, so please don't judge me for showing a simple example instead. I have a table that looks like this:

| main_col | some_metadata | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| this | True | 10 |
| this | False | 3 |
| that | True | 50 |
| that | False | 10 |
| other | True | 20 |
| other | False | 5 |

I want to normalize this data separately for each case of `main_col`. For example, if we're to choose min-max normalization and scale it to range [0; 100], I want the output to look like this:

| main_col | some_metadata | value (normalized) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| this | True | 100 |
| this | False | 30 |
| that | True | 100 |
| that | False | 20 |
| other | True | 100 |
| other | False | 25 |

Where for each case of `main_col`, the highest value is scaled to 100 and another value is scaled in respective proportion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform('max')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the max per group, then normalize in place:

```
df['value'] /= df.groupby('main_col')['value'].transform('max').div(100)
```

or:

```
df['value'] *= df.groupby('main_col')['value'].transform('max').rdiv(100)
```

output:

```
  main_col  some_metadata  value
0     this           True  100.0
1     this          False   30.0
2     that           True  100.0
3     that          False   20.0
4    other           True  100.0
5    other          False   25.0
```

Comment: I've just realized both of our solutions assume the numbers are positive. In case of any negative numbers, the result can be highly skewed. For instance if  `this False` is `-10` instead of `3` the result will be `-100` instead of `0`.

Comment: @NuriTaş I don't think this should be the case as it's not a min/max scaling but a max scaling, 0 being the implicit min.

Comment: @nuri-taş that's true. But if there were negative values it's not the implementation that would be wrong, this whole normalization just wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The normalization formula you are looking for is `100 * (x / x.max())`:

```
df.groupby(['main_col'])['value'].transform(lambda x: 100 * (x / x.max()))
```

Result:

```
0    100.0
1     30.0
2    100.0
3     20.0
4    100.0
5     25.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```